# search and replace text in all java files in a package

Tags: java, android

I am using a few functions in my application which i want to replace with other functions (to make it backward compatible)
My question : is it possible to find & replace some specific text in all java files in a package with some tool, or do i have to do it manually on every java file? I have a LOT of java files in the package.

For eg : i want to replace

```
getExternalCacheDir()
```

with something like

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory + "/Android/data/<package_name>/cache/"
```

the IDE i'm using is Eclipse Helios. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *Search - File...* in Eclipse, search for `getExternalCachDir()` in `*.java`, then right click in the *Search* view, choose *Replace All...*, enter the replacement text, and click OK.

Comment: This is the right tool. You can narrow down the search by first selecting a node of your workspace in the package explorer window.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse, Just do

```
right click on function->Refector->Rename
```

or

> select method + press  shift+alt+R

This will change your method name through out the project.

Comment: The question is about replacing function calls. That's not the answer to this problem.